# Разбить файл на части python

Tags: python-3.x

В общем есть книга, нужно разбить её по главам (для пакета gensim, чтобы gensim.corpora.textcorpus.TextCorpus() воспринимала каждую главу как документ. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Регулярные выражения это обработка строк. Добавьте в вопрос через кнопку `править` текущую строку и что из нее должно получиться. А почему нужны именно регулярные выражения?

Comment: Не обязательно регулярные выражения, мне нужно  обычный txt документ разбить на части(главы),так,чтобы пакет gensim воспринимал их как отдельные документы (хочу  LDA алгоритмом темы выделить, а когда пытаюсь создать корпус каждая строка принимается за документ и получается несуразица )

Comment: Думаю, вы долго будете ждать специалиста по gensim, который не факт что поможет... Если ваш вопрос -- обработка текста, то и добавьте в вопрос пример текста и что должно получиться. Как там этот текст будет обрабатывать gensim уже другой вопрос и к теме отношение имеет небольшое